# Nlog - What parameters are available to me for database logging via Web.Nlog XML

Tags: xml, parameters, nlog, target

Basically what i'm trying to do is include the logger name in my database write:

```
<rules><logger name="**LogEntry**" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="apiLog" final="true" /></rules>
```

this is the code i'm using to call my SPROC to write to the database:

```
<!-- database target -->
        <target name="apiLog" 
                xsi:type="Database"
                connectionStringName="NLog"
                commandText="exec dbo.InsertApiLog
                                @level,
                                @name,
                                @callSite,
                                @type,
                                @message,
                                @stackTrace,
                                @innerException,
                                @additionalInfo">
                <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
                <parameter name="@name" layout="${DisplayName}" />
                <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite}" />
                <parameter name="@type" layout="${exception:format=type}" />
                <parameter name="@message" layout="${exception:format=message}" />
                <parameter name="@stackTrace" layout="${exception:format=stackTrace}" />
                <parameter name="@innerException" 
                            layout="${exception:format=:innerFormat=ShortType,Message,Method:MaxInnerExceptionLevel=1:InnerExceptionSeparator=}" />
                <parameter name="@additionalInfo" layout="${message}" />
        </target>
```

How can i adjust the @name parameter to pull the logger **Name** property from my rules member?

Additionally, is there a good source that lists out all the parameter layouts available to me for error storage? I'm referring to this part of my data store ref:

```
<parameter name="@type" **layout="${exception:format=type}**" />
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For the logger name you could use `${logger}`

All layout renderer are listed here: https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers. You can click on the layout renderer there for their options.